# How do I restrict user to select only single checkbox in gridview which i created dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-3.0

I have created a checkboxes into data grid view in winform application dynamically.

```
 DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn myCheckedColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
                {
                    Name = "MyColumn",
                    FalseValue = 0,
                    TrueValue = 1,
                    Visible = true
                };
```

I want to restrict user to select only single checkbox at a time.

Is there any direct property?

> I googled and found this answer but CellContentClick event does not get trigger as checkboxes created dynamically.

```
 private void mydatagridview_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value))
                {
                    int currentcolumnclicked = e.ColumnIndex;
                    int currentrowclicked = e.RowIndex;
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in associatinggridView.Rows)
                    {
                        dr.Cells[currentcolumnclicked].Value = false;
                    }
                    associatinggridView.CurrentRow.Cells[currentrowclicked].Value = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using radio buttons instead of check boxes?

Comment: no as per design we have to use check boxes as design is generic :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests the CellContentClick is raised for all Cells, no matter how their columns are created.

```
void mydatagridview_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int col = yourCheckboxColumnIndex;
    for (int r = 0; r < mydatagridview.Rows.Count; r++)
        if (r != e.RowIndex && e.ColumnIndex == col ) 
            mydatagridview[col , r].Value = false;
}
```

Comment: yea now me also able to call raised an event :) but how do I restrict user to not to select multiple check boxes any clue ? thanks

Comment: Well, that's what the above code __does__: Uncheck every cell but the one that was clicked!