# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns of a DataGridView permit multiple Rows checked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I've a datagridview on which i've added a checkBoxColumn. It also have a datasource, it is a List of Object whit set and get; It also have a boolean properties "Checked" used for the checkBox column.. It gets the data from this source as it should with all its boolean states for the checkboxes in the datagridview, but when i click on the checkbox it will only allow one checkbox to be checked at a time. I can i select multiple rows and also set to true the bounded "Checked" properties?

```
public class MyDatasource {
        public MyDatasource (){}
        public Boolean Checked { get; set; }
        public String description  { get; set; }
}
```

i've added this as DataSource for my grid with class `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource`

and also add this cell click event

```
private void my_grd_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;

    var dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
    var cell = dataGridView[0, e.RowIndex];

    if (cell.Value == null) cell.Value = false;
    cell.Value = !(bool)cell.Value;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restrict user to select only single checkbox in gridview which i created dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668308/how-do-i-restrict-user-to-select-only-single-checkbox-in-gridview-which-i-create)

Comment: Sorry, i've answered the question wrong. My grid permit to check only one row but i don't want it.. i would like the opposite behaviour

Comment: OK, in that case the question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851554/c-sharp-change-datagridview-cells-by-dragging-on-them/26854496#26854496), despite its slightly confusing title..